# How do you check RAM voltage from Linux (can't see that on BIOS)

Tags: memory, bios

I have an Elitebook 2570p with 4gigs DDR3L 1600 freq and I just added 4gigs DDR3 (same) freq 1600 because it was pretty cheap.

I found that even though most people say it's OK to mix the two, some did have problems.

But most generally the people with DDR3 who added DDR3L that were asking, I'm in the contrary situation.

I would like to check my the voltage on which runs the components of my Computer, especially the processor and the DDR3L RAM to see whether it is dual voltage, and whether there would be no prob with the DDR3.

Does any one know of a way to check that? my bios (68ISB Ver. F.31) does not give that info (btw a lot of its features are grayed-out)

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/dmidecode/?platform=linux i hope you solve your problem

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'd really like to know, too!

Answer (score 7):

Use dmidecode with type 17

`sudo dmidecode --type 17`

Output

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0005
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Other
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 1(top)
    Bank Locator: ChannelA
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0005
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 2(under)
    Bank Locator: ChannelB
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Ramaxel
    Serial Number: 436BC413
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: RMT3170MN68F9F1600
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

See bottom of the output, ram voltage is specified there. I have two ram slots, I am using only the second one and configured voltage for that slot is:

```
Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

Answer (score 5):

I've used `dmidecode`.

```
dmidecode -t [type] (use 5 for voltage and 17 for memory details.)
```

ie.
   dmidecode -t 5

> **Type List**
>
> ```
>  0   BIOS
>  1   System
>  2   Base Board
>  3   Chassis
>  4   Processor
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  5   Memory Controller
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  6   Memory Module
>  7   Cache
>  8   Port Connector
>  9   System Slots
> 10   On Board Devices
> 11   OEM Strings
> 12   System Configuration Options
> 13   BIOS Language
> 14   Group Associations
> 15   System Event Log
> 16   Physical Memory Array
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 17   Memory Device
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 18   32-bit Memory Error
> 19   Memory Array Mapped Address
> 20   Memory Device Mapped Address
> 21   Built-in Pointing Device
> 22   Portable Battery
> 23   System Reset
> 24   Hardware Security
> 25   System Power Controls
> 26   Voltage Probe
> 27   Cooling Device
> 28   Temperature Probe
> 29   Electrical Current Probe
> 30   Out-of-band Remote Access
> 31   Boot Integrity Services
> 32   System Boot
> 33   64-bit Memory Error
> 34   Management Device
> 35   Management Device Component
> 36   Management Device Threshold Data
> 37   Memory Channel
> 38   IPMI Device
> 39   Power Supply
> ```

Man [dmidecode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode)

Some content was taken from [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/dmidecode-finding-out-hardware-details-without-opening-the-computer-case).

> P.S : It works with MoBo with **DMI zone**

Comment: This is what i'm getting when I use *dmicode -t 5*:

# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Comment: weird, did you tried with cpu-g?, cpu-z alternative

Comment: When I do : **dmidecode -t memory** I do get info but nothing about voltage.

Comment: y because -t memory is equal than -t 17 , just download the tarball in official site and run it with python.

Comment: seems like cpu-g does not give info about RAM voltage

Answer (score 0):

You can download CPU-Z to get voltage info.

Comment: I am pretty sure CPU-Z only runs on Windows.

Comment: Ack, I thought they made a Linux version.